# MATLAB: Expand table display to show contents of each cell

Tags: matlab

I have a table as follows:

```
T = 
     N            V  
____________    _____
[4x3 double]    22497
[4x3 double]    22319
[4x3 double]    22263
[4x3 double]    22120
```

I wish to have `T` displayed so that every matrix in `N` is expanded inline. Is this even possible?

Comment: To my knowledge, I don't think there is.  I just skimmed through the MATLAB documentation and I don't see any functions that help prettify the output of tables

Comment: Generally speaking this may be possible. However, you will need some dirty Java hacks in order to manipulate the table cells. I would not recommend to do this. Start e.g. at this page looking for how to do this in principle: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/

Comment: @pyStarter, I agree. That seems to be a lot of sidetracking for something that I presumed wasn't even a niche feature.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this problem myself.  Messy data, can you believe it?

Unfortunately, I see no other way but a for loop (I am relatively inexperienced at MatLab to begin with).  Here is a function that takes a table and the number designating the variable in the table (in your case, 1).

```
function tableprime = expandtable(temptable, field)

    tableprime = temptable;
    count = 1;

    for i = 1:height(temptable) 
        C = temptable{i, field};
        if length(C{:}) > 1 
            temp = tableprime(1:count-1,:);
            for j = 1:length(C{:})
                temp  = [temp; tableprime(count,1), table(C{1}(j), 'VariableNames', {temptable.Properties.VariableNames{field}}), tableprime(count, 3:17)];
            end
            tableprime = [temp; tableprime(count+1:height(tableprime),:)];
        end
        count = count + length(C{:});
    end
end
```